# flash text area not detecting img tag height

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, cdata

I have a text area that I'm adding html (within a CDATA tag of course) to from an xml file. The text is adding fine and the field is scrolling fine when I add extra text, but as soon as I an `<img>` to it the image shows up but the fields inner height (the overflow part) does not adjust for the `<img>` so i can't scroll down to see the rest of the image (I even added a width and height, but to no aval ).

Is there a way to adjust the inner height of the text field via as3 so the field can be scrolled to the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 0):

i think you'd be better off with webview or something. Text area has htmlmode, but not all features are supported. Plan B: you can implement your own parser, what makes the text as you want it.